# (JQuery) I'm wondering why this code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have narrowed it down to the line that declares the '`position`'

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var sliders = new Array("#left","#middle","#right");
        var links = new Array("#fLink","#sLink","#tLink");

        $(".link").click(function(){

            var position = $("#" + sliders[links.indexOf("#" + this.id)]).position().left();

            alert(position);

            $(".slider").animate({left:gap}, 1500);

        });

});
```

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? Any error or what???

Comment: You have to be more specific. What does "doesn't work" mean? You're getting an exception? It's just not working? etc.

Comment: what is happening?  Are errors in firefox?

Comment: are you concatenating "#" with "#left" and thereby selecting the wrong id?

Comment: FWIW, a better way to write `var sliders = new Array("#left","#middle","#right");` is `var sliders = ["#left","#middle","#right"];`.

Answer (score 5):

`sliders` already has the `#` in it, you don't want to add it again when using it within `$()`, you end up passing `"##left"` in as the selector string. Also note that `left` is a value, not a function, so no `()` after it.

So:

```
var position = $("#" + sliders[links.indexOf("#" + this.id)]).position().left();
// Remove -------^^^^^^ and -------------------------------------------------^^
```

---

For what you're doing, I wouldn't use a pair of arrays, I'd use:

1. A lookup object, or
2. A naming convention, or
3. A `data-*` attribute

The last two are trivial, but here's how that first one would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sliders = {
        "fLink": "#left",
        "sLink": "#middle",
        "tLink": "#right"
    };

    $(".link").click(function () {

        var sliderSel = sliders[this.id];
        if (sliderSel) {
            var position = $(sliderSel).position().left;

            alert(position);

            $(".slider").animate({
                left: gap
            }, 1500);
        }

    });

});
```

---

Side note: Is `gap` defined somewhere in code you haven't shown? If not, you'll want to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I forgot to change 'gap' to something else.